# Angular 8 - How to override BrowserModule for multi-apps lazy loading?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

Having tested successfully a sub-app routing, I called then the same sub-app from its parent app, but this time the routing doesn't work and the following console error is shown:

> Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to
>   common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module,
>   import CommonModule instead.

With the following code I am trying to override the sub-app BrowserModule with CommonModule that should be exported to the parent app, because BrowserModule should be used only once, and in fact, it is already used by the parent `app.module.ts`. So my sub-app `app.module.ts` is as follows:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'module1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../sub-app1/src/app/module1/module1.module').then( module => module.Module1Module )
      },
      {
        path: 'module2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../../sub-app1/src/app/module2/module2.module').then( module => module.Module2Module )
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
      ]
    })
    export class SubApp1Module {}
```

So what can be done to get the routing working from the parent app?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be importing AppModule from SubApp1Module.

- Remove that "AppModule" import and you should be OK.
- If there is something in AppModule that you would like to to share with other modules, create a "SharedModule" and import that one instead.

Comment: I had tried the approach of "SharedModule" but didn't work for me, with that one I was getting some error message like the following: AppComponent is used in AppModule and SharedModule, try to move AppComponent to the higher level module, It looks like that the mentioned method works only sub-apps use routing with components, not modules. Here is the approach I had tried: https://github.com/kievsash/Core-App-monorepo/blob/master/projects/app1/src/app/app.module-export.ts

Comment: I can guarantee you should not import AppModule in any submodule. Ever. If you're having issues with SharedModules you can skip that part for now to at least get your application running. The temporary downside will be having to re-import the same services in every module all the time.

Comment: My application is running without any compiling error, just routing for some reason doesn't work, and I get the browser console error related to BrowserModule, and here is another example that imports AppModule into an exporting sub-module: https://github.com/hql287/angular-sub-apps-setup/blob/master/projects/sub-app1/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @Sami-L I don't see AppModule being imported into another module in your example.

Comment: App1SharedModule is returning AppModule and App1SharedModule is imported into the main app.module.ts (parent app).